# Error in Databricks SQL Warehouse: User is not part of org

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I tried to start the Databricks SQL Warehouse cluster today, but received the following message:

> Clusters are failing to launch. Cluster launch will be retired
> Request to create a cluster failed with an exception: PERMISSION_DENIED: User xxxx is not part of org: xxxx

I believe the error is due to a senior member the left our team last week. When he left we removed him from the admin-group, and now we receive the error message above.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: hi @Joakim Torsvik, to resolve this issue, you need to add user account back to the admin-group or assign a new admin account with required permissions.

Comment: According to [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/api/sql-endpoints#get) there's a link between SQL warehouse and the user who created it - apparently this is causing trouble. Probably it's worth raising to Databricks as a bug. Best is to delete the warehouse and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I created a SQL warehouse in databricks with below requirements:

[image]

When I am starting the cluster, I got below error:

[image]

In my case due to cluster size I got above error. I changed cluster size from X-Large to small

[image]

I stopped all the SQL warehouses and I tried again to start the SQL warehouse cluster, it started successfully.

[image]

In your case there may be issue related to the permission
Add the user and manage the permissions

[image]

Otherwise delete that and create new cluster.